# Upload a file if I have file contents in postman

Tags: c#, file-upload, postman

I don't have a physical file, but from azure blob  I got contents of file. I have file contents as string.. How can I Upload this content  i.e. the contents of file using POSTMAN

Comment: You need to do a better job explaining what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your code/ requests. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly of what you are trying to do : submit a file that you got from an Azure Blob into Postman, then I think you should simply **save the file on your hardrive**, and then submit it through Postman.

Postman cannot natively use a stream to send it somewhere else, you will need to script at least (or create another small piece of software using c#, but it is off-topic).

Comment: Yes, I don't want to save locally. So from Azure blob i get contents , I just want to upload the contents, whiteout saving it.

Comment: Postman cannot handle that without scripting. And even with scripting I am not sure.